# SQL Server: how to select records with specific date from datetime column

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a table with one column `dateX` formatted as `datetime` and containing standard dates.

How can I select all records from this table where this dateX equals a certain date, e.g. May 9, 2014 ?

I tried the following, but this returns nothing even if I have several records with this date.

```
SELECT     *
FROM         dbo.LogRequests
WHERE     (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dateX, 101) = '09/05/14')
```

Edit: In the database the above example looks as follows, using SQL 2012: `2014-05-09 00:00:00.000`

Comment: is that supposed to be May 9th or September 5th?

Comment: You are right. And yet the documentation for [SQL Server Cast and Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) shows that the 101 format is `mm/dd/yyyy`, you should've been using 103 instead. But using an open range is the better choice. And if every row has `00:00:00.000` as the time part, then you can simply use: `dateX = '20140509'`

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The easiest way is to convert to a date:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.LogRequests
WHERE cast(dateX as date) = '2014-05-09';
```

Often, such expressions preclude the use of an index.  However, according to various sources on the web, the above is sargable (meaning it will use an index), such as [this](http://msmvps.com/blogs/robfarley/archive/2010/01/22/sargable-functions-in-sql-server.aspx) and [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea).

I would be inclined to use the following, just out of habit:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.LogRequests
WHERE dateX >= '2014-05-09' and dateX < '2014-05-10';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this ! That works great. :) Will accept as soon as I can.

Answer (score 2):

For Perfect `DateTime` Match in SQL Server

```
SELECT ID FROM [Table Name] WHERE (DateLog between '2017-02-16 **00:00:00.000**' and '2017-12-16 **23:59:00.999**') ORDER BY DateLog DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM LogRequests
WHERE cast(dateX as date) between '2014-05-09' and '2014-05-10';
```

This will select all the data between the 2 dates